# ディレクトリ構造を変更したい ／ 下にある階層を全て選択して権限を引き継いで上へ移動

Tags: linux

**環境**
・CentOS 6.4

---

**現状**
・/var/www/hoge/public/dir1/ 
・/var/www/hoge/public/dir2/ 
・/var/www/hoge/public/.htaccess
・/var/www/hoge/public/index.html

---

**やりたいこと**
・publicディレクトリ階層を削除したい
・/var/www/hoge/dir1/ 
・/var/www/hoge/dir2/ 
・/var/www/hoge/.htaccess
・/var/www/hoge/index.html

---

**質問**
・下にある階層全てを選択して上へ移動するのは下記で合っているでしょうか？
・その際、権限の引き継ぎはどう設定するのでしょうか？
・mvコマンドは、cpコマンドみたいに、aオプションとかは使用しなくても良い？

```
mv /var/www/hoge/public/* /var/www/hoge/
```

Comment: /var/www/home/ 以下には、重複するファイルが絶対にないという前提でいいのでしょうか？

Comment: ファイル名が重複している、という意味でしょうか？　重複ファイルがあるとマズいのでしょうか？

Comment: 例として `/var/www/hoge/.htaccess` が既に存在していた場合、バックアップを取るのか、それとも上書きしていいのかで実装が大きく異なります。

Comment: なるほど。移動だけだとどちらか分からないですね。上書き、のつもりで質問しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# cd /var/www/hoge/public/
# mv * .??* ../
# cd ../
# rmdir public
```

Comment: mv * .??* ../ はどういう意味でしょうか？

Comment: `*` は `.` で始まらない全てのファイルやディレクトリ、`.??*` は `.` で始まる全ての(若干の例外あり)ファイルやディレクトリです。それら全てを親ディレクトリへ移動します。若干の例外とは、`.` + 1文字、ですが、そんなファイルやディレクトリはたぶんないと思いますので、問題ないと思います。

Comment: mv * だけでは . で始まる内容を移動できないんですね。勉強になりましたー